# Exception raised with unittest assertions

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertions, python-unittest

When I run a unit-test where I am testing for equality of two integers, I get an assertion error exception instead of unittest reporting a failure, then proceding to the next test.  Here is the test code (greatly simplified to prove the point).

```
import unittest

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_method(self):
        myVariable = 1
        self.assertTrue(myVariable==0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
builtins.AssertionError: False is not true
File "C:\Dev\Volleyball\test.py", line 10, in <module>
  unittest.main()
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 124, in __init__
  self.runTests()
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 270, in runTests
  self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\runner.py", line 168, in run
  test(result)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\suite.py", line 67, in __call__
  return self.run(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\suite.py", line 105, in run
  test(result)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\suite.py", line 67, in __call__
  return self.run(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\suite.py", line 105, in run
  test(result)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 498, in __call__
  return self.run(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 446, in run
  self._executeTestPart(testMethod, outcome, isTest=True)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 391, in _executeTestPart
  function()
File "C:\Dev\Volleyball\test.py", line 7, in test_method
  self.assertTrue(myVariable==0)
File "C:\Program Files\python32\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 527, in assertTrue
  raise self.failureException(msg)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I misunderstanding how test assertions work?

For the record, I am using Python 3.2.1 on Windows 7.

TIA, Alan

Comment: Confirmed it works fine on Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Your code works for me on Win7 Python 3.2.  Have you run your stripped-down sample?  The stack trace has subtly different line numbers.

Comment: I had deleted a couple of lines, hence the line no. mismatch.  Just to make sure I wasn't going mad, I cut+paste the above code into a brand-new file called test.py and re-ran it, with the same results.  The old traceback has been edited to show the latest traceback.  Any further ideas would be appreciated.  Regards.

Comment: Ok, I've made a breakthrough.  Under the Windows command line the test works as expected and I get the correct failure message.  However, when I test from within WingIDE (where I do most of my development, testing and debugging), I get the above exception.  Any ideas how to cure this?  TIA

Comment: Are you using the WingIDE Testing Tool or just running the test script with the interpreter?

Comment: In an old changelog, I see `* Debugger always stops on AssertionError exceptions and never on
  SystemExit exceptions by default.  This behavior can be changed via
  preferences.` Have you tried changing this preference? Edit: Read-reading this, it's probably irrelevant.

Comment: confirmed it works as it should on both Python2.6.7 and 3.1.3 on Debian

Comment: @agf - I only have Wing personal edition, which doesn't have the testing tool, so I am running the test script with the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right - thanks to @agf I have reached an acceptable compromise.  I have removed AssertionError from the 'Always Report' section of the 'Debugger:Exceptions' and now the debugger no longer stops on the assertion.  The downside is that while this is fine while running a test script (because I will see the results in the failure list), when running the 'real' program I will have to keep an eye on the 'Debug I/O'
output to view assertions.

Thanks to all who replied.

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of self.assertTrue(myVariable==0) try using self.assertEqual(myVariable, 0)

Comment: Good idea, but has the same effect :-(.  Regards